# Compare to Columns and write match to File

Tags: bash

first off, i have two .csv files.

The first looks likes this:

```
email;md5
testuser@gmail.com;a18bf786efb76a3d56ee69a3b343952a
testuser@test.com;ed53e691ee322e24d8cc843fff68ebc6
richard@hotmail.com;c1a2cfbf08a049a874271aecbf0dbf77
```

The second .csv looks likes this:

```
md5
ed53e691ee322e24d8cc843fff68ebc6
e197b72a853f375ae6a2bff84a90d88b
a9654d30d08b2e03666b5e41a2179f3b
```

what i want to do is, compare the md5 columns and write the email of the matching md5 string in a file.

The Export should look like this, cause the md5 hashes of file 1 and 2 matched, the result is the clear E-Mail Adress.

testuser@test.com

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You are expected to show your code attempt and tell us where it failed. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's a requirement, where's your implementation?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -f md5 email | grep -v 'email;md5' | cut -d';' -f1
```

Will match all the substrings found in `email` that accure in `md5`.

Since the first lines will match, we can use another `grep` to prevent matching on `email;md5`

Then using `cut` we can split the csv (`-d';'`) and only show the fist column (`f1`)

---

Output:

```
testuser@test.com
```

---

[To write the output to a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file), use:

```bash
grep -f md5 email | grep -v 'email;md5' | cut -d';' -f1 > output.txt
```

Comment: How to write the Output in a file? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: While the chances for a MD5 hash to appear in an email address are negligible, that's probably not the case for the literal string `md5`; I would prepend a `;` to each line of the md5 file `grep -f <(sed 's/^/;/' md5) | ...` (+1)

Comment: Looks good.  I need to use the to csv files.  First ist email.csv and other is email_md5.csv

Comment: Change the first part of the command from `grep -f md5 email` to `grep -f email_md5.csv email.csv`

Comment: I get no Output in the .txt at the end.